# "Set foot on" vs "set foot at"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I want to know which sentence is correct.

1. After a two-hour flight, we set foot on Okinawa
2. After a two-hour flight, we set foot at Okinawa

I can't find the right preposition.

Comment: Please add more detail to explain why this is confusing for you?  Otherwise the question may be closed as simple *proofreading*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The first sentence is correct. "Set foot at" is very rare, per [this Google Books Ngram Viewer chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=set+foot+at%2C+set+foot+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cset%20foot%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cset%20foot%20on%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cset%20foot%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cset%20foot%20on%3B%2Cc0), compared to "set foot on".

"at" would imply a specific place, rather than a general one (like the island of Okinawa). Something like "set foot at the very spot on Ellis Island where our grandparents had once stood".